# ActiveState Perl CPAN dmake not working

Tags: windows, perl, activestate, dmake

I have  ActiveState Perl 5.20 32bit on windows 7 64bit.
I want to install mudules from CPAN but always ends this:

```
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SH\SHAY\dmake-4.12.2.2.zip ok
Package contains both files[ChangeLog COPYING dmake.exe META.yml NEWS PATCH.TXT
README.TXT] and directories[man readme startup]; not recognized as a perl packag
e, giving up
Configuring S/SH/SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip with Makefile.PL
Running make for S/SH/SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip
dmake.exe:  Error: -- No target
  SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
```

Comment: I used ActiveState Perl before, and as long as the module is precompiled by them, downloading it worked fine. Any other module, just forget it. Then I switched to Strawberry Perl and after that, no problems.

Comment: Yes the PPM work well but i need some modules that I only find in cpan

Comment: Why are you trying to install `dmake` anyway? As far as I know ActivePerl now comes with all the necessary tools to build modules from CPAN. And it's not an ordinary Perl module anyway so CPAN can't install it for you

Comment: this is a example, i want to install SDL and other modules but always ends like this: dmake.exe:  Error: -- No target

Comment: I was getting this... re-installing ActiveState Perl fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi Kergtot,
Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue?
I'm getting the same on my W10 box.  I've tried reinstalling Perl and still get the problem.
So my next plan is to install dmake manually - but the notes on the web for this are a bit limited.
I note that PPM is not installed with Perl - at least it didn't install for me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I used the latest ActivePerl 5.28 under Win7, and got the same error:
`Running make for C/CO/CONKLIN/MIDI-Perl-0.83.tar.gz 'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. CONKLIN/MIDI-Perl-0.83.tar.gz dmake -- NOT OK`.

I had a look into `C:\Perl64\cpan\build` folder and I have found there both modules I tried to install with CPAN:

```
MIDI-Perl-0.83-0
MIDI-Perl-0.83-0.yml
XML-Simple-2.25-0
XML-Simple-2.25-0.yml
```

Inside those folders I've found a `lib`folder. So, I just copied the content of `C:\Perl64\cpan\build\MIDI-Perl-0.83-0\lib` into `C:\Perl64\lib` and so on, and both modules were recognized during execution of my scripts and worked well.